# How to use break - until in a loop?

Tags: ruby, loops

I try to write a loop to get two different random numbers, here's my code and it works fine.

```
loop do
  a = rand(1..9)
  b = rand(1..9)
  break unless a == b
end
```

But when I change the unless to until, the loop doesn't break. I don't know why.

```
loop do
  a = rand(1..9)
  b = rand(1..9)
  p a
  p b
  break until a != b
end
```

Comment: `until` repeats the statement (or block) until the condition becomes true. It is a loop, not a conditional. It is the opposite of `while`. Since it is a loop, if it gets executed, `break` will exit this smaller one-line loop, not the big `loop do... end` loop. It is `if` that is the opposite of `unless`; is that what you meant to write?

Comment: Thank you Amadan, that's what I need  : )

Comment: (`a, b = (1..9).to_a.sample(2)` is the standard way of doing this.)